# backbone and generic events that are bound to page html rather than to a Backbone view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am evaluating moving some jQuery code to Backbone and have a total noob question. I have a large set of jQuery events that exist on just standard html (not associated with a backbone view). What is the proper place to handle those. Something simple in jQuery:

```
<div class='my-thing'>click me</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.my-thing').on('click',function(){
       alert('say hello');
     });
  });
</script>
```

In Backbone, it would seem to be something like:

```
events: {
     "mouseenter .my-thing":"say_again"
 },
 say_again: function(){
   alert('i want to say something');
 },
```

But where would I put this? Or structure this?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would organize them by view -- that's where you declare the events.  This requires modularizing the layout of your UI to make it possible to restrict each event to the scope of the view.

**Template**

```
<script type='text/template' id='say-template'>
    <div class='say-container'>
        <div class='my-thing'>click me</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**View**

```
var SayView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.render();
    },

    el: "#container",

    template: _.template($("#say-template").html()),

    events: {
        "mouseenter .my-thing": "say_again"
    },

    say_again: function() {
        alert('i want to say...');
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    }
});

var sayView = new SayView();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

[Here's a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm5eH/3/)

---

Of course, nothing is stopping you from wiring up events in the normal way in the global scope of the application, if you need to.  It's just best to avoid as doing that tends to break the MVC pattern.

Comment: thx, dbaserman - 2 dumb questions but (1) in your initialize method, why do we need to have the `_.bindAll(this,"render");` - It looks like the second line should be able to handle the outputting of it? Does it force a rebinding of the all events (such as mousenter)? and (2) I know this is the idiomatic style for Backbone but is there a way to use it just to structure our events? Kinda a halfway between what we currently have and doing it in this style? thx for answer

Comment: thx for demo - really nice; looks like you might have edited for Q2 above - but is there a logical way to structure if within backbone or should we just put it outside of backbone. I currently don't have a terrible solution but just curious if you have a strong opinion one way or another

Comment: @timpone the `_.bindAll` is just to ensure that `render` has the context of the view when it gets invoked (ie, so that you can use `this.model` and `this.template`).

Comment: @timpone do you mean where all the logic of defining the views and creating instances should go?

Comment: thx @dbaseman more, if there was a logical place to put our currently defined jQuery events without migrating them to Backbone style esp for events that are capture as just straight html. One other quick question about the bindAll (and I know my example is really trivial) but I commented out the bindAll line here http://jsfiddle.net/Xm5eH/6/ and it still worked ok? In general, do I really need to have it? I know that managing this is a little tricky in Javascript and just don't want to have more than I really need due to my lack of experience. thx again

Comment: @timpone you're right, I guess `bindAll` isn't needed ... I know it's needed sometimes, but I'm a bit confused now.  As far as the events, I really think it would defeat the point of using Backbone to have a bunch of inline events, but whatever floats your boat.  I guess if the events are largely static (don't update the view or the model data), then it might work ok.

Comment: cool, thx - really helpful - might try to rephrase this and ask a new question